# VSCode change default python version

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I code on VSCode and  don't specify a python version it is set to python2.7.17

I would like to set it by default to python3.6

I tried doing so by adding this at the top of my script : `#!/usr/bin/python3.6` But it is not working

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from datetime import timedelta
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

This code outputs :

```
2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
```

I can it output the version 3.6 ?

My settings.json looks like this :
[image]

Even with a specified path the sys.version outputs python2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VSCode's command palette choose the option

`Python: Select Interpreter`

And choose the interpreter you want to use. This will automatically add the setting correctly to your `settings.json` file in your `.vscode` folder for your workspace.

[image: python list vscode]

This will take care of Python management in VSCode.

Now coming to setting the right python to be used by your os/terminal when trying to run scripts.

Since you are using linux, make sure your python is the right version thats linked

1. Check python version on terminal - `python --version`
2. execute `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 1` << verfiy your paths correctly
3. then run `sudo update-alternatives --config python`
4. Select the python version
5. Try `python --version` again and check

If on Windows make sure path to Python 3.8.x is set at a higher priority in your Path Environment Variable. Py3 should be above your other paths

[image: Path for Python]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I reopen everytime my vscode it always goes back to python2

Comment: can you check what version of python is default on your system by running `python --version`. I added info to add alternatives and manage python versions.

Comment: @Reda Could you please tell us what fixed your problem, so other people who may have this problem can learn?

Comment: I think their problem wasn't vscode's linting but actually executing python scripts. Basically, the second part were their solution (path/python version) and not related to vscode directly

Answer (score 6):

Open settings and search for `Python Default Interpreter Path`.

[image: VS code settings for default python interpreter]

In your case, you wish to set it to `/usr/bin/python3.6`. Though I would suggest using a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

```json
{  
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3.6"
}
```

If you are using virtual environment, [to ensure that the terminal is using the associated python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environments-and-terminal-windows), check the second option `Python > Terminal: Activate Environment`:

[image: Activate Python Environment in VS Code]

In `settings.json` it is called `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true`.

One reason your change did not persist, was because in your screenshot, you opened your *workspace's* `settings.json`.
To make it default, you should edit your *user's* `settings.json` instead.
This you can access with `Ctrl+Shift+P`, `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`.
Detailed instructions can be found in the documentation ["Manually specify an interpreter"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter), including using environment variables as the interpreter's path.

Also, `"python.pythonPath"` [has been deprecated](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md):

> 2021.6.0 (16 June 2021)
> 5. Added python.defaultInterpreterPath setting at workspace level when in pythonDeprecatePythonPath experiment. (#16485)
> 8. Show python.pythonPath deprecation prompt when in pythonDeprecatePythonPath experiment. (#16485)

> 2020.7.0 (16 July 2020)
> 9. Prompt users that we have deleted pythonPath from their workspace settings when in Deprecate PythonPath experiment. (#12533)

> 2020.5.0 (12 May 2020)
> 6. Do a one-off transfer of existing values for python.pythonPath setting to new Interpreter storage if in DeprecatePythonPath experiment. (#11052)
> 8. Added prompt asking users to delete python.pythonPath key from their workspace settings when in Deprecate PythonPath experiment. (#11108)
> 12. Rename string ${config:python.pythonPath} which is used in launch.json to refer to interpreter path set in settings, to ${config:python.interpreterPath}. (#11446)

> 2020.4.0 (20 April 2020)
> 13. Added a user setting python.defaultInterpreterPath to set up the default interpreter path when in Deprecate PythonPath experiment. (#11021)