# debug python in vscode failed

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm unable to debug my python code in vscode. I've attempted to redownload python and add it to PATH, but I'm still getting the same errors as before.

When I press F5, the terminal shows the image 1, and later, image 2 shows automatically.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: windows 10 1909    python  3.8.3   vscode 1.4.6

Comment: Your path setting to your python is wrong. Please verify if you have the right path set. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62377335/vscode-change-default-python-version/62377463#62377463

Comment: Python seems to be working OK. Python complains it can't open the launcher. Then VSC has an timeout connecting to the launcher because it is not running. You are probably using VSC 1.46.

Comment: Does the file that can't be read exist? What about the permissions on that file and Python? Are they compatible?

Comment: @Brett Cannon @ rioV8  @ tHeSiD  Thanks bro   i reinstalled my system yestersday,and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the problem of python but the 'Python' extension. You can try to reinstall it. If it does not work, you can try to install other versions of 'Python' extension(Hit the "manage" button on the extension -> Install Another Version).